# How to update a record without selecting that record again in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Hi all I am doing something like this -

```
void update(ClasstoUpdate obj)//obj is already having values to update...
{
  var data= (from i in Entityobject.ClasstoUpdate 
            where obj.Id==i.Id
            select i).FirstorDefault();
  data.Name="SomeCoolName";
  EntityObject.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want to perform an update without again querying using the Id,is there any way I just pass the updated object to ADO.NET Entity framework and it updates it.I am sorry if I am missing something here but this is the way i have been doing it wondering if there is a simple way to update. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple way to update an object is fetch it, change it, and submit changes which is what you're already doing.

Another way is to [attach the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx), and tell the entity framework that the object is in a modified state.

A third way is to update the object by constructing an SQL string that updates the object directly in the database without fetching it. However I wouldn't recommend doing this.

A side note: remember to check for null in your function. If you know the return value of `FirstOrDefault` will never be null then you should use `First` instead. You might also want to consider using `Single` instead of `First`.

Comment: I am sorry i just made an example..ya i would do that...i am going to update the query...what i wanted to know was whether i could just pass that updated object somehow to update

Comment: can you provide an example of the attach scenario ?